# Why does the sun jdk source code not contain the javax.servlet package?

Tags: java

I tried to find the source code of the javax.servlet package in the jdk source code, but it seems the jdk doesn't contains the package. Where can I download the package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why the sun jdk source code dose not contains the javax.servlet package?

Because it is part of Java EE, not Java SE.

> where can I download the package?

The JARs are part of your Java EE platform; e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a peek at what the source itself would look like here [1] are the sources for javax.servlet in Apache Geronimo and [2] for glass fish.

[1] http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/geronimo/specs/trunk/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec/src/main/java/
[2] http://svn-mirror.glassfish.org/glassfish-svn/branches/BuildDeploymentTest/web/javax.servlet/